# I'm frustrated with college because I feel like I'm never given the opportunity to explore the material

Tags: independent-researcher, physics

I'm a freshman at a private polytechnic institute, and I'm very disillusioned with the whole idea of college. I feel incredibly pressured with the work here and often find myself depressed. Oftentimes I have to find supplementary material online to cover the gaps in the material, since I can't always understand the teaching styles of the professors or the textbooks. I always feel like I'm required to know the information, but never have time to understand it. I want to study theoretical physics, and couldn't care less about going into industry. During high school, I was able to breeze through the required courses, and spent my extra time going above and beyond. Instead of filling my spare time playing games and hanging out with friends, I spent it reading, learning about modern physics theories and the upper limits of human knowledge pertaining to the universe. Here, I have no time to explore, no time to understand, and no time to think. I only have the time to study what I need to know and regurgitate it on tests. I can't remember most of physics 1 because I felt so rushed by work.

I feel that I might be able to do better studying independently over the next three years, learning physics from its foundations to current theories, beyond what they teach at college. I don't care about the "college experience", I came to understand physics. I don't feel like that's happening, even with the material already covered. I'm considering dropping out or transferring to an easy state school back home, so I can breeze through the work and focus on understanding and learning again. What should I do?

Comment: I'm sorry you're having such a hard time at college, and I hope things improve for you soon. However, this question is about the high school-to-undergraduate transition, which is a fundamentally undergraduate experience, and this site is about graduate-level education and beyond (as per the [help/on-topic]). (The answer to this question would be very different for a grad student, so this isn't a question that can be generalized to grad study in order to remain in scope.)